# What does this symbol mean? It was found on a circuit board of an old projection tv

Tags: schematics

Two horizontal lines with three slashes in between.

```
_______
__\\\__
```

The bottom line is solid, I just couldn't find a way to draw it that way.

Comment: What? 8 years old? I'm impressed with your good language.

Comment: The way you "draw it that way" is you take a good, in-focus, detailed picture of the symbol about which you are asking, then include the image in the question. Details matter, particularly in engineering. You state you found the symbol on a circuit board. Why try to do an ASCII line drawing of the symbol, when you could have much more accurately shown the actual symbol?

Answer (score 5):

[image]This is probably what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

That's an older/alternative way of depicting a Capacitor in a schematic.

Answer (score 1):

That's an older/somewhat more unusual symbol for an electrolytic capacitor.  They often come in a "can" form factor such as the one depicted below:

[image: radial aluminum electrolytic cap]